# Entity framwork better error explanation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, entity-framework-5

I'm using a databasefirst approach with Entity framwork and MVC 4(asp.net) and do now and then get the following error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the     foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

Most likly I have an unintentional null-reference which comes is due to any part of the conversion step(from view, to viewmodel, to databaseobject through automapper).

What I would like to know is if there are some way to get the information WHERE the problem is, which foreign key that is causing the issue. I have tried tracing the database but it seems like the application knows before trying to save to database that there are issues. Can I somehow debug this? Get more error info?

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors can be frustrating because they can be hard to track down.

I would start with purging all the data from the database (back it up if required).

Then, open the database in Management Studio and drag and drop the tables onto the visual designer. Then you get a visual clue of what the relationships look like. You might get a surprise!

Answer (score 0):

These type of errors may be occurred if you changed your database schema(model) and your database have some data.
two or more tables have relationships using foreign key.

**Possible Solution**

drop the database and apply migrations again.

Comment: Dropping the database is not a solution at all, as you lose all the data. You must make accomodations around the old data for the new constraint instead, by updating or deleting beforehand.